# Find Ext's - 'easy' cases.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

First exercise:

Let $k$ be a field and $R=k[x]/x^2$. Find $\operatorname{Ext}^{1}_{R}(k,k)$.

Second exercise:

Let $A$ be a torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Prove $\operatorname{Ext   }^{1}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z},A) = \operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(A,U(1))$ where $U(1)$ is a multiplicative group of complex numbers of modulus $1$.

That domain of mathematics is crazy. I have no power here. I just want to survive first course of that and not continue learning those things.

Comment: What have you tried? Instead of complaining about "that domain" of math, your time in this question may be better spent detailing your attempts or difficulty in why you are stuck on this problem.

Comment: @kamills In first exercise, I don't know how to find injective resolution for field. I need it to put derivative functor on it.

Comment: @kamills in the second one, I know that torsion Z-module = torsion abelian group. I also don't know how to find injective resolution for A.
I'm complaining because it is my 11th algebraic course on studies and I did better in previous ones, with more 'classical' algebra.

Comment: @MaciejFicek For the first one, there's an obvious free resolution of $k=(k[x]/x^2)/(x/x^2)$. Can you see it?

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier I see that k is of form You wrote. But I don't see what it gives.

Comment: In your profile you say that you like Algebra, Number Theory and Topology, I hope you know that each of these subjects extensively use methods of homological algebra. It is surely normal to struggle a bit if you see these things the first time but as kamills said, it's not time to complain but rather to persevere.

Comment: @QiZhu Sir, I was spending a lot of hours on that course and it was completely sad for me. It was the hardest course during my studies. I did not persevere that course.

Answer (score 1):

**Exercise 1**

As pointed out in the comments, $k$ has a free resolution as

$$\cdots \to R \xrightarrow{x} R \xrightarrow{x} R \to k \to 0$$

where $R \to k$ by $a + bx \mapsto a$ (equivalently, $x \mapsto 0$). Taking the deleted resolution and applying $\operatorname{Hom}_R(-, k)$ we get

$$0 \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,k) \xrightarrow{x^*} \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,k) \xrightarrow{x^*} \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,k) \to \cdots$$

where $x^*: \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,k) \to  \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,k)$ is the map induced by multiplication by $x$. This sends a map $\varphi: R \to k$ to the composition $R \xrightarrow{x} R \xrightarrow{\varphi} k$. Even more explicitly, we have $x^*(a+bx) = \varphi(x\cdot(a+bx)) = \varphi(ax) = ax\varphi(1)$. This is zero because the $R$-module structure on $k$ is given by $(ax+b)\cdot c = bc$.

Since $x^*$ is the zero map, the homology at position $1$ in the above complex is precisely $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,k)$. Thus $\operatorname{Ext}_R^1(k,k) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_R(R,k)$. The latter is isomorphic to $k$ via $\varphi \mapsto \varphi(1)$, so $\operatorname{Ext}_R^1(k,k) \cong k$.

**Exercise 2**

The exercise as stated is incorrect, since $\operatorname{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^1(\mathbb{Z},M) = 0$ for any abelian group $M$ since $\mathbb{Z}$ is projective. The correct statement is $\operatorname{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^1(A, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(A, U(1))$.

For this, consider the short exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R} \to U(1) \to 0$ where the first map is inclusion and the second map sends $\theta$ to $e^{i \theta}$. This gives a long exact sequence for $\operatorname{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^1(A, -)$:

$0 \to \operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(A, \mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(A, \mathbb{R}) \to \operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(A, U(1)) \to \operatorname{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^1(A, \mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^1(A, \mathbb{R}) \to \cdots$

However, note that $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(A, \mathbb{R})=0$ since $A$ is torsion: for any element $a \in A$, a homomorphism $A \to \mathbb{R}$ must send $a$ to a torsion element in $\mathbb{R}$, which is torsion-free. Lastly, $\operatorname{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^1(A, \mathbb{R})$ is zero since $\mathbb{R}$ is injective (it's a divisible abelian group).

Therefore, the map in the long exact sequence $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(A, U(1)) \to \operatorname{Ext}_\mathbb{Z}^1(A, \mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: In definition of Ext, there is right derivative functor. Andthe right derivative functor means I need to work with injective resolution. Injective resolution is of form 0->my object -> I_0 -> i_1 -> etc.. it is on the right side. So why did You took resolution from left and then moved it to right and what means 'free' resolution or 'deleted' resolution? I dont know these adjectives.

Comment: Usually when being presented with Ext, you get shown a way to compute Ext via injective resolutions of the right-hand object or projective resolutions of the left-hand object, and it's proven that these approaches yield the same result. Is this not (yet) something you learned? It's often much easier to come up with projective resolutions than injective resolutions.

Comment: A "free" resolution is a resolution by free modules terminating in the object of interest; in particular, free resolutions are projective resolutions. As for "deleted," if $\cdots \to P_1 \to P_0 \to M \to 0$ is a (projective) resolution of $M$, its deleted resolution is $\cdots \to P_1 \to P_0 \to 0$ (this is no longer exact at position 0, but it's still a chain complex). You do the same thing when computing Ext via injective resolutions: you remove the object of interest from the sequence before applying Hom.

Comment: I know that one should remove object before applying Hom. I dont get why You use projective (left) resolution when Ext is about injective (right) resolution.

Comment: @MaciejFicek Please see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#Definition) or some standard textbook on the subject.